# fabric:/System/InfraustructureService is not healthy on Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I deployed a fresh Service Fabric Cluster with a durability level of Silver and the `fabric:/System/InfrastructureService/FE` service is unhealthy with the following error:

> Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.InfrastructureService',
>   Property='CoordinatorStatus', HealthState='Warning',
>   ConsiderWarningAsError=false. Failed to create infrastructure
>   coordinator: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Fabric.InfrastructureService.ManagementException: Unable to get
>   tenant policy agent endpoint from registry; verify that tenant
>   settings match InfrastructureService configuration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The durability level needs to be specified in two places: the VMSS resource and the Service Fabric Resource in the ARM template.

My template had it set to Bronze in the VMSS resource and silver in the Service Fabric resource - once I made them match, it worked.

Comment: to clarity, we changed Reliability Tier to Silver (in the service fabric resource) via PowerShell, where is the corresponding VMSS options, i do not see it.. do you need to re-deploy the VMSS? 

Comment: This did it for me. I had to update the VMSS durability tier through resources.azure.com.